# unable to convert date-time string "$var days" error in tcl How to convert it?

Tags: tcl

```
set a [clock scan now]   ;# today's date
puts [clock format $a]
puts "Enter a number up to where you have to increase"
set var [gets stdin]
set var [scan $var %d]
set a [clock scan {$var days} -base [clock seconds]]
puts [clock format $a]
```

It is showing some error that is

> unable to convert date-time string "$var days"

Comment: Because a literal string `$var days` is indeed a not a valid representation of a timestamp. Please consult [the relevant part of the tutorial](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl4.html). You're advised to complete it fully as well.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong quotes:

```
clock scan {$var days}      ;# non-interpolating quotes: "doesn't work"
clock scan "$var days"      ;# OK
```

Try using [`clock add`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/clock.htm#M5) for date arithmetic

```
% set a [clock seconds]
1507652391
% clock format $a
Tue Oct 10 12:19:51 DST 2017
% set var 5
5
% set b [clock add $a $var days]
1508084391
% clock format $b
Sun Oct 15 12:19:51 DST 2017
% set var -2
-2
% set b [clock add $a $var days]
1507479591
% clock format $b
Sun Oct 08 12:19:51 DST 2017
```